# Is it possible to connect remotely via ADB to a device without connecting to the same Wi-fi network

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to somehow interact with the device via Android ADB remotely, that is, without a local USB connection and without connecting to the same WiFi network. That is, for the user to download the application, give permission to postpone and this device could connect to the server and it was already possible to work with it remotely at the developer level.

I was looking for a solution on the Internet, came to the conclusion that it is possible only via USB or with root rights, but in any case only by connecting to one Wi-Fi network. Maybe someone knows some secret)

Comment: adb is an unprotected plaintext protocol. using it outside of a trusted (home) network will expose the device to serious security risks and therefore is not recommended (hackers could take-over the adb connection and issue any commands they want).

Comment: this is understandable. Well, the very fact of implementation is possible and if so, how?)

Comment: It is possible but it works different than you want. Use an Android 11 device and perform a Wifi pairing. That is what is supported by default. Not sure if it is restricted to local Wifi. Usually the biggest problem is that you need a direct TCP connection to the device as server, which is not possible behind NAT gateways (by Wifi routers or e.g. carrier grade NAT gateways).

Comment: It depends entirely on the device you are using, some even support ethernet adapters so adb is not restricted to wifi in any way.